# C# fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping

How should the following mapping configuration be solved?

```
public abstract class RepositoryEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Descriptor : RepositoryEntity
{
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Proxy<TDescriptor> : RepositoryEntity
{
    public virtual TDescriptor Descriptor { get; set; }
    public virtual Byte[] SerializedValue { get; set; }
};

public class TestUnit : Proxy<Descriptor>
{

};
```

I receive problems when testing the `TestUnit` mapping - **it says it's impossible to map the item with generic parameters**. This happens if I attempt to map every class from the specified before.

If I attempt to map everything, except `Proxy<T>`, then I receive that there is `no persister for the 'TestUnit'`.

If I stop inheriting `TestUnit` from `Proxy<Descriptor>`, the mapping test *works fine*.

---

***Does `Fluent NHibernate` have possibility to automap types inherited from some concrete  `Class<T>` template? Could you help me with mapping these entities?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a combination of Fluent and Auto mappings.

Fluent mappings should be used for generics.

```
        Configuration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().InMemory)
            .Mappings(x =>
                      {
                          x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<RepositoryEntity>();
                          x.AutoMappings.Add(autoPersistenceModel);
                      });
```